# Soldering 2 usb cables into a single micro usb

Tags: usb

Sorry if this in the wrong place, but I'm not sure where else to post, and I'm not sure where to look, either.

Basically, I want to solder 2 female USB-A ports to a single micro USB-B plug, so that 2 devices (such as a keyboard and mouse) can be plugged in simultaneously. Is this a straight-forward process or does this require a whole interface to be built?

Reason for this is that I would like to plug those into my android device, but currently I can only plug in 1 device at a time.

Any replies will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires at minimum, a USB hub. USB's architecture doesn't allow for the line to be split electrically like that by just connecting two sockets to a single plug.

For your use case, you might be able to just use a regular USB hub (with appropriate connector cable) to connect multiple USB devices to your android device. I don't know if there is a limitation on the android device on if it can support hubs when it is in host mode, that's something you'd want to look into.

And there's a [stack exchange website for electronic engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com), which might be a great place for this type of question.

Comment: Havent seen that site before, thanks. Will look into it

Answer (score 1):

This would not work, what you need is a USB hub. Two USB devices on a single header without a hub is not a supported configuration within the USB standard and just plain wouldn't work.